# stm8l fluctuating results in Floating point operation

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, adc

I was doing a project in STM8L151C6 based measuring the voltage using ADC with 12 bit resolution and a external reference voltage of 2.5 V.

It has a 4 digit seven segment display. So I tried to output the ADC Reading to it. For most of the time the ADC reading stays stable and is fine for the time being.

Now the problem starts. I converted the ADC reading to analog voltage read by the ADC using formula:

```
voltage = ADC_reading * 2.5 / 4095.0
```

Here, `voltage` is of type `float` and `ADC_reading` is of type `uint16_t`.

The output value in voltage is fluctuating when I measure a constant 107mV at the ADC pin externally by using a multimeter. My output reading is fluctuating between 88mV and 132mV - it never stays constant.

I tried averaging the readings by **adding 64 readings and then right shifting 6 times** to divide it by 64, but the fluctuation never stopped. Since outputting the ADC value didn't fluctuate much (for most readings it didn't fluctuate), I be under the impression that, the problem is with floating point calculation.

```
for an input of -
107mV - ADC reading I got is 176
213mV - ADC reading I got is 356
328mV - ADC reading I got is 530
540mV - ADC reading I got is 885
```

after conversion to voltage using above said formula
I am getting fluctuated results as
`88mV - 122mV for ADC reading 176`
`531mV - 562mV for ADC reading 886`

It's not stabilizing.

What should I do to fix the fluctuations, so that I will get a stable reading?

Comment: Not sure but division probably has higher precedence over multiplication. Maybe you wanna do `voltage = (ADC * 2.5) / 4095.0`. BTW, what is this 4095.0?

Comment: 12 bit resolution gives 4096 divisions (0 - 4095) so i gave higer value as 4095.0 just to make sure it is a float.

Comment: Since there is no addition and subtraction and only just multiplication and division, I suppose higher precedence is not a problem. either way is correct, isn't it?

Comment: You should provide some data, like what are the ADC values are their corresponding voltage values that you expect and what you get.

Comment: These seem to be actual results, what are the expected results?

Comment: @kiner_shah I had provided some more data.

Comment: If ADC reading is stable and the same value is fed to the code (that formula line), this seems unlikely, the formula should give same result. I would recommend debugging in the code, you may use print statements or any debugger which is supported and check what values are fed each time.

Comment: To wrap up the infos in the question and the comments (BTW, please [edit] your question and add such information there): If you display the integer conversion result, it is quite stable (I would expect small fluctuations +/-1..2). But if you use your floating point calculation, it is not stable and flutuates much more. Is this correct?

Comment: Feed some integer constant into your floating point calculation and see if that is stable. If not, you have a programming error. It is very unlikely that the compiler system has an error.

Comment: Calculate manually the result for some measured integer and then the same plus/minus 1. Does the results deviate in the range of the watched fluctuation?

Comment: Can you share the code how you convert and print the values you get (ideally, a [mre]). If you use `printf` you may be using wrong format specifiers.

Comment: @chtz I didn't print it out to stdout. Its ouputted to 7 segment displays I connected to the controller.

Comment: So, what DO you do to output your float variable? Provide a MRE!

Comment: @chtz Its a 4 digit 7 segment display . I convert the float into char array and display each characters to it. I already done it as a module and is working perfect. Also I am not rounding the float. Just display those digits to the display.